# How to insert variable which contain array value in wp_options table?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query

I have create a form and i want to store the form data in `wp_options` table so for that i have created this query

```
$insertquery = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wp_options`(`option_name`,`option_value`) VALUES ('smsfactory123','asdasdf')");
```

Now when i am importing the static data then it doesn't create any problem when i pass the variable which is containing array it shows me error.

```
$apidetail = array(
    'userid' => $uid,
    'userpassword' => $upwd,
    'senderid' => $sid,
    'ono' => $ono,
    'message' => $message,
    );
```

This is how i am getting value of array in variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also use `json_encode()` function instead of `serialize`.

```
$var = json_encode($array);
update_option('option_name', $var);
```

Comment: So it will insert data into wp_options table?

Comment: You could also consult the small green martians, but for some reason you don't attempt to do that, if serializing is a waste, json is just idiotic.

Comment: Well Well Well it works for me so now i come to know that how to insert value in wp_options table thanks a lot @maximus L

Answer (score 1):

You can save array with update_option function like below code.

```
update_option('option_name', $arr_store_me);
```

Comment: why do you serialize the value?

Comment: It is not necessary but i suppose they need to save array in one meta so it is best.

Comment: beyond the slight waste of CPU, It gives the impression it is needed....

Comment: Hey i am creating plugin for first time so i want to insert data to wp_options so the way you are telling is it save the value to option_value?

Comment: Yes, You do not need to serialize values. If the value needs to be serialized, then it will be serialized before it is inserted into the database.

Comment: One more thing if i want to give option_name so i have write it like you does above but with static value? I think so